# How to display SQLException while insert or update operation

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working with SQLite android where I am using an ***sqLiteDatabase.insert*** function to insert customers and ***sqLiteDatabase.update*** to update customers and getting the result which is always a long variable, When result is -1, I know the database operation was not successful but I want to display the actual **SQLException** that occurred. As the return type of these methods is long so they only print the exception in log. Is there any way to get the message of **SQLException** and display in Toast etc.
I tried to use try catch to catch the exception and show message but when exception occurs it doesnt go to catch block. Below is my code

```
public void insertData(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, Context context, ContentValues values, DatabaseOperation dbOperation, DatabaseOperationCallback dbOperationCallback) {
    JSONObject resultObj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        if (dbOperation != null) {
                 sqLiteDatabase.insert(dbOperation.getTableName(), null, values);
            }
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        //showing in toast; this is not triggered

    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
        //showing in toast; this is not triggered


    }

}
```

Please see below picture for reference. Any help will be appreciated
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
e.printStackTrace(); // (directly to the log)
```

or

```
e.getMessage(); // returns message as a String
```

or others as per the Java Exception Class.

However, using the insertOrThrow method, is probably the method that you want to use.

Comment: i added try catch block to show this but when the exception occurs it doesn't go to catch block. please see my edited question.

Comment: @NS answer updated, try insertOrThrow rather than insertWithOnConflict.